# Por que iframe não abre alguns sites?

Tags: javascript, html5

Alguém sabe me explicar por que alguns sites não abrem no `<iframe>` e se existe alguma solução parecida com `<iframe>`?

O **Google** e **PagSeguro**, por exemplo, não abrem.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com.br" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

O **Google** e outros sites utilizam [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options), uma forma de prevenir o [*Clickjacking*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking), que é uma espécie de roubo de cliques para que o usuário pense que está fazendo uma ação num determinado site, mas na verdade os cliques executados nessa ação estejam sendo usados pelo atacante, para executar operações maliciosas.

São aplicados no cabeçalho *HTTP* do servidor para esses ataques através de `<frame>`, `<iframe>` ou `<object>`.

Acredito que uma forma de passar por cima disso é utilizando *proxy*, mas isso não vou saber te dizer como fazer.

Answer (score 0):

É possível implementar código em javascript que detecte se o site está a ser aberto numa iframe. Não sei se o google usa esse mecanismo, mas se usar, pode ser esse o caso.

Também existem mecanismos semelhantes para PHP e provavelmente outras linguagens server-side, embora não sejam tão fidedignos.